# How to find a pair of solutions of Linear Diophantine equation such that you minimize this expression?

Tags: diophantine-equations, euclidean-algorithm, linear-diophantine-equations

This is a typical Math coding Problem I encountered here [Problem](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1031).
So Let me break it to you 
Suppose you have two values $a$ and $b$ and to select this  value $a$ one time it takes you $c_1$ cost and it takes $c_2$ cost to use value $b$.
You are to solve this equation for $(x,y)$ 
 $ax$ + $by$ = $N$ where $N$ is a value given to you 
Find such $(x,y)$ that you minimize this expression $x*c_1 + y*c_2$. 
 or report if it is not possible to solve 
 
It is a clear cut Linear Diophantine equation and I can easily solve for $(x,y)$ by using Extended GCD But I don't how to do it by minimizing the given expression.
An example for this question is suppose you have $a=3$ $b=4$ and $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2=2$ and $N=43$

 $x=13$ and $y=1$ can do the trick for us  by minimizing  the given expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d>0$ be the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Fix an arbitrary solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of the equation $ax+by=N$. Let $(x,y)$ be any solution of this equation. Then $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=0$, so $d(x-x_0)|b$, that is $x=x_0+kb/d$ for some integer $k$. Conversely, for any integer $k$, $(x_0+kb/d, y_0-ka/d)$ is a solution of the equation. This solution costs $c_1(x_0+ kb/d)+c_2(y_0-ka/d)$, which is $k(c_1b-c_2a)/d$ than the cost of the solution $(x_0,y_0)$. This follows that a solution of the equation with the minimum cost is:

- a solution with minimum $x_1$, when $c_1b>c_2a$,
- a solution with    minimum $x_2$, when $c_1b<c_2a$,
- any solution of the equation, when    $c_1b=c_2a$.